# Getting an error when trying to run seed in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm using [Nwidart][1] module package and I'm trying to create a seeder using a factory. But when I try to run `php artisan db:seed` I get this error

> Call to undefined function Modules\Products\Database\Seeders\factory()

Here is my ProductsDatabaseSeeder.php

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Products\Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Modules\Products\Models\Product;

class ProductsDatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

        factory(Product::class, 10)->create();
    }
}
```

My ProductFactory

```
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use Modules\Products\Models\Product;

$factory->define(Product::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title' => $this->faker->title,
        'price' => $this->faker->randomNumber(3),
    ];
});
```

My Product.php

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Products\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [];
}
```

Full error

```
  Call to undefined function Modules\Products\Database\Seeders\factory()

  at Modules/Products/Database/Seeders/ProductsDatabaseSeeder.php:25
     21▕ 
     22▕ 
     23▕ 
     24▕ 
  ➜  25▕         $product = factory(Product::class, 10)->create();
     26▕ 
     27▕ 
     28▕     }
     29▕ }

      +8 vendor frames 
  9   database/seeders/DatabaseSeeder.php:20
      Illuminate\Database\Seeder::call()

      +24 vendor frames 
  34  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

This is what I get after changing

```
    factory(Product::class, 10)->create();
```

to

```
    Product::factory()->count(10)->create();
```

```
  Class 'Database\Factories\Modules\Products\Models\ProductFactory' not found

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:656
    652▕     public static function factoryForModel(string $modelName)
    653▕     {
    654▕         $factory = static::resolveFactoryName($modelName);
    655▕ 
  ➜ 656▕         return $factory::new();
    657▕     }
    658▕ 
    659▕     /**
    660▕      * Specify the callback that should be invoked to guess factory names based on dynamic relationship names.

      +1 vendor frames 
  2   Modules/Products/Database/Seeders/ProductsDatabaseSeeder.php:25
      Modules\Products\Models\Product::factory()

      +8 vendor frames 
  11  database/seeders/DatabaseSeeder.php:21
      Illuminate\Database\Seeder::call()


  [1]: https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v6/introduction
```

Comment: show the FULL error

Comment: there is no `factory` helper function in Laravel 8 ... the way factories work has been changed ... please check the laravel documentation for this

Comment: I've updated my question to include the code change I did and the new error I got.

Comment: you can install a package to bring back the old way of dealing with factories ... if not you will need to create a factory class for the model, which you can call the factory class directly you don't have to go through the model, but if you want to call `factory` on the Model you would need to override a method so it knows where to look for your factory potentially

Answer (score 1):

As of Laravel 8 which is what you probably use - as you are using the HasFactory trait - you will need to call

```php
Product::factory()->create()
```

In order to run the factory

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/please-help-call-to-undefined-function-factory?signup

Comment: I've updated my question to include the full error, because when I added `Product::factory()->create()` I got this error `Class 'Database\Factories\Modules\Products\Models\ProductFactory' not found`

Comment: One thing that has to be changed aswell is the definition of a factory for laravel 8 - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#writing-factories - however, that will not solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Apart from adding the HasFactory trait to your model, in order to support the Modules{Module} namespace you need to put this in your model:

```
    /**
     * Create a new factory instance for the model.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory
     */
    protected static function newFactory()
    {
        return \Modules\Module\Database\Factories\ModelFactory::new();
    }
```

So, in your model Product.php

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Products\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

     /**
     * Create a new factory instance for the model.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory
     */

    protected static function newFactory()
    {
        return \Modules\Products\Database\Factories\ProductFactory::new();
    }

    protected $fillable = [];
}
```

Also, since laravel 8 the conventions of using a factory has changed.
So, in your

ProductsDatabaseSeeder.php

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Products\Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Modules\Products\Models\Product;

class ProductsDatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

        Product::factory()->count(50)->create();
    }
}
```

And, finally the factory class ProductFactory.php like

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Products\Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

use Modules\Products\Models\Product;

class ProductFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = Product::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'title' => $this->faker->title,
            'price' => $this->faker->randomNumber(3),
        ];
    }
}
```